# How to facebook share an image with text in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-share

I have to share some text with an image in a div on facebook. I have tried this,

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
FB.init({
    appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true }); 
};
(function(d, debug){var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if(d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; 
    js.async = true;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);}(document, /*debug*/ false));
function postToFeed(title, desc, url, image){
var obj = {method: 'feed',link: url, picture:image,name: title,description: desc};
function callback(response){}
FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
```

and this,

```
jQuery(function(){
     jQuery('.btn-fb').click(function(){
    var elem = jQuery(this);
    postToFeed(elem.data('title'), elem.data('desc'), elem.prop('href'), elem.data('image'));
    return false;

    });
    });
```

I have created api and it is working fine. But when I click on share button it shares site home page text and not what I want. Here is the screengrab of what I want to share http://prntscr.com/it7kyh .

Comment: Had you done any proper research on this, you would know by now that Facebook does not let you specify these value at run-time any more, but takes all this info from the OG meta tags of the shared URL ...

Comment: yes, I searched a lot. but my data is in a popup of gallery which i have to share. so how can I do this?

Comment: By sharing a URL that returns the correct OG meta data for the combination of title, description and thumbnail that you want to share. If you don’t have one, you will need to create one.